# Histogram rebinning with interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have histogram data in counts `a` and weights `b` format, such as:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[2,3,6,7,1]
```

If I plot the histogram binning into 5 or less bins, it correctly plots, and rebins:

```
plt.hist(a,weights=b,bins=5)[0]
```

[image]

However, if I try to rebin to more than the count length (in this case 6 or more), the histogram leaves out one count.

```
plt.hist(a,weights=b,bins=6)[0]
```

[image]

Any ideas how to rebin with interpolation? There is the long way of manually decompsing the data, interpolating it into the new bins and the reconstructing, but I'm thinking there must be some numpy/scipy trick for this.

- In image processing circles this is often *histogram equalization*

Comment: If you have a count of 5 numbers, how do expect it to bin it into 6 bins without leaving "one out"?

Comment: In this case the 3rd bin would be a bit taking from 2nd and a bit from the 4th - could be linearly, with exponential decay, with a normal distribution, anything.

Comment: So, replace any 0 count by the average of its neighbors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 6 bins for 5 values. And because histogram is merely a very simple (one can even say "stupid") counting of values, you logically have to have at least one empty bin. In this case, the bin edges are something like [1, 1.66, 2.33, 3.00, ...]. Left edges are inclusive, right (with the exception of the last one) are not => the [2.33, 3.00) does not contain any of your values.

There is no correct way of "making your histogram better" and therefore no obvious numpy/scipy trick. Interpolation does not make any logical sense unless you have strong reasoning for the meaning behind your numbers. In principle, you may use kernel density estimate ( https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html ) but again, with 5 values, its usefulness is very dubious.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! - of course my real data does not only have 5 data points, thiis is only an example i threw together : )